# Isomorphic groups between 2 sets

Tags: group-theory

Show that the group $C_4 = \{ i, -1, -i, 1\}$ of fourth roots of unity in the complex numbers isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Can anyone please help me start this problem?

I know that $C_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are isomorphic if there exists a bijective map between them that makes the multiplication table of one group match up with the multiplication table of the other.
I know $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{[0], [1], [2], [3]\}$.

Thank you

Comment: The best way to show two groups are isomorphic is to actually write down a putative isomorphism and then prove it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $C_4$ is abelian and that it contains an element of order $4$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function $f: C_4\rightarrow \Bbb Z_4$ such that $f(xy) = f(x) +_4 f(y)$ for every $x,y \in C_4$

***Hint***:

What function translates multiplication into addition? That is what function of $x$ and $y$ when multiplied with each other would simplify with a term containing the sum $(x + y)$?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$, $i^4=1$.

More generally, $i^{4k}=1$, $i^{4k+1}=i, i^{4k+2}=-1$, $i^{4k+3}=-i$.